# ob_get_contents NO contents on server

Tags: php, caching, ob-get-contents

I got a very strange problem.
Today I tried to implement caching into my PHP application.

It works like a charm on my localhost WAMP server (Windows 8).
But it does not work online.

Hence I do not have a clue what I am doing wrong.

The code is somewhat like:

```
<?php

function write_cache(){
$contents = ob_get_contents();

/// do something with contenst (like writing it..
}

$tpl_content = 'loooooong string'; // gets filled throughout the application

echo $tpl_content;

/// should be filling the cache
write_cache();

?>
```

This should work. I echo it hence it is in the buffer.
And I am somewhere doing it correctly because locally it is working.

But online it remains empty..

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Where is your `ob_start()` call?

Comment: If this is required. Then this would be the solution.
Will try this tomorrow! Would be great if this would solve it.

Still I am a little surprised why this worked locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@faintsignal

You where right!! ob_start(); was missing.
It is probably not needed on a WAMP server.

But on a LAMP server it is needed.

The code now looks like:

```
<?php

ob_start();

function write_cache(){
$contents = ob_get_contents();

/// do something with contenst (like writing it..
}

$tpl_content = 'loooooong string'; // gets filled throughout the application

echo $tpl_content;

/// should be filling the cache
write_cache();

?>
```

And it works!!

Thanks!!!!